# ReferenceError: angular is not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I am trying to create a quiz application.so for that i created a module and controller using angular js , i dont know the problem it showing the 
ReferenceError: angular is not defined

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="codeWar">
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="page-header">
        <h1 class="text-success">Raja's Programming Quiz</h1>
        <h3>
          <small>Learn about the programming languages below before you decide to take on <thead>
          <strong>Programming Quiz</strong></small>
        </h3>
      </div>
      <div class="" ng-controller="listCtrl as list">
        <p ng-repeat="pLanguage in list.data">
            {{pLanguage}}
        </p>

      </div>
    </div>


    <!-- Our Application scripts -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/controller/list.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/app.js"></script>
    <script src="angular/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

I created list module to load the json data in the view

**list.js**

```
(function() {
    angular
          .module("codeWar")
          .controller("listCtrl", ListController);
          function ListController() {
              var view_model = this;
              vm.data = programmingLanguageData;
          }
          var programmingLanguageData = [
            {
                language:"C",
          image_url:"https://lh3.ggpht.com/vrKC4cLAuEFf2-FdDfc02iuCHa5TnPRd-uecZZY8vCzxFnCN-C0PGZ-qsTKeKSIVacA=w300",
          paradigm:"Imperative (Procedural) , Structured",
          creator:"Dennis Ritchie",
            },
            {
                //json data
            }

          ]
})();
```

**app.js**

```
(function() {
      angular
            .module("codeWar", []);


})();
```

**Error in log**

> ReferenceError: angular is not defined - list.js:2:5
>
> ReferenceError: angular is not defined - app.js:2:7
>
> Error: No module: codeWar - angular.min.js:17:76

Comment: Change the sequence of files, angular.min.js must be the first to be included

Comment: Move `angular.min.js` to head section

Answer (score 1):

You need to import angular before using it

```
<script src="angular/angular.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/app.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/controller/list.js"></script>

use this example http://jsfiddle.net/Lvc0u55v/3332/
```

Comment: i added it, still same problem

Comment: did you change the order to first import the angular.min.js and then everything else?

Comment: Error: [$injector:nomod] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.9/$injector/nomod?p0=codeWar

Answer (score 0):

try to change the sequence of the js order upper angularjs then your local script, It should work...

```
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/controller/list.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/app.js"></script>
```

Comment: <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular.min.js"></script>  try this... remove ur local angularjs script.

Comment: in answers only, just replace the local script to http link....remove your app.js It s not needed, you are initialized module twice , why?!!!

Comment: where you can get json data, use http service to get json data from local, I did not get your method to get json...

Comment: change vm to view_model, or declare programmingLanguageData  as global should work. if this too not work try to change some values like view_model.data ='blabla', if this works your json format is not good.

Comment: Nothing display in view page, in console log it showing this error               Error: [$injector:nomod] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.5/$injector/nomod?p0=codeWar

Comment: i put that in my app.js , but i dont need any dependcies

Comment: Any way you have to put [] empy...var myApp = angular.module('codeWar', []); create this myApp .controller(..........).

Answer (score -1):

Give this a try

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/controller/list.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/app.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js">    </script>
    <script src="angular/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

If it doesn't work then put all your scripts between `</body>` and `</html>`.

Comment: this is a bad practise

Comment: can you tell me which one ?

Comment: put it as last tag inside <body>

Answer (score -1):

You should load angular.js first
Your scripts order should be like this:

```
<script src="angular/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/app.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/controller/list.js"></script>
```

Comment: jquery should be imported before angular